# How to get data from a df and place it to another df at cell level - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes df_criterias and df_tofill.

df_criterias

```
     goto_emptycol1     goto_emptycol2    data1     data2
0    some value1        another value1    a         val1
1    some value2        another value2    b         val2
2    some value3        another value3    c         val3
3    some value4        another value4    d         val4
4    some value5        another value5    e         val5
5    some value6        another value6    f         val6
6    some value7        another value7    g         val7
```

df_tofill

```
     emptycol1          emptycol2         data1     data2
0                                         f         val6
1                                         nok       nok
2                                         nok       nok
3                                         a         val1
4                                         nok       nok
5                                         g         val7
6                                         d         val4
```

expected_results

```
     emptycol1          emptycol2         data1     data2
0    some value6        another value6    f         val6
1                                         nok       nok
2                                         nok       nok
3    some value1        another value1    a         val1
4                                         nok       nok
5    some value7        another value7    g         val7
6    some value4        another value4    d         val4
```

From both I created 2 lists with indexes (where some criteria from both dfs, columns "data1", "data2" - matched)

```
list_fill = [0,3,5,6] #from df_tofill
list_crt = [5,0,6,3] #from df_criterias
```

Where list_crt[0] element 5 is a match with list_fill[0] element 0.

To make the expected_results I'm trying this:

```
for i, icrt in enumerate(list_crt):
        #Get the value
        val1 = df_criterias.loc[icrt,"goto_emptycol1"]
        val2 = df_criterias.loc[icrt,"goto_emptycol2"]
        #Set the value
        df_tofill.loc[list_fill[i], "emptycol1"] = val1
        df_tofill.loc[list_fill[i], "emptycol2"] = val2
```

I'm struggling to get the "expected_results" df. Is the algorithm correct?

UPDATE:
Managed to make it work - .at gives me some strange errors I replaced it with .loc. An .reset_index() was needed before creating the lists with indexes.

The lists of indexes was created using this:

```
def common_elements(crtlist, radlist):
    #where crtlist is all criterias and radlist all to be checked
    #returns 2 lists with indexes where elements where a match
    crtli_idx = []
    radli_idx = []
    for idx1, crt in enumerate(crtlist):
        for idx2, rad in enumerate(radlist):
            if rad.startswith(crt):
                crtli_idx.append(idx1)
                radli_idx.append(idx2)    
    return crtli_idx, radli_idx


crtlist = ['1', '21', '444']
radlist = ['asda','aererv','1vrvssq','4447676767']
idxcrt, ixdrad = common_elements(crtlist, radlist)
print(idxcrt, ixdrad)
OUT:
[0, 2] [2, 3]
```

Comment: Can you please provide some reproducible code, e.g. paste `df_tofill` and `df_criterias` or the first few rows? `df.head().to_dict()` is usually a good method. In addition, if you want more responses read through [mcve].

Comment: I'm guessing that your column names in `df_tofill` are strings. `'0'` and `'1`'.  Try `df_tofill.at[list_fill[idx], '0']`.  Also, is there a reason why you are using `loc` for `df_criterias` and `at` for `df_tofill`.  You should be able to use `at` for both.

Comment: @ClimenteAlin, Did the below solution help?

Comment: I didn't wrap my head around around that yet, but I will remember it for the next time I need to do something similar. thank you @jpp :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to align indices / columns, replace `''` by `np.nan` in target dataframe, then just assign one dataframe to the other via `.loc`.

```
df_criterias = df_criterias.rename(columns={'goto_emptycol1': 'emptycol1',
                                            'goto_emptycol2': 'emptycol2'})\
                           .set_index(['data1', 'data2'])

df_tofill = df_tofill.replace('', np.nan)\
                     .set_index(['data1', 'data2']) 

df_tofill.loc[:] = df_criterias.loc[df_criterias.index.isin(df_tofill.index)]
df_tofill = df_tofill.reset_index()

#   data1 data2   emptycol1      emptycol2
# 0     f  val6  somevalue6  anothervalue6
# 1   nok   nok         NaN            NaN
# 2   nok   nok         NaN            NaN
# 3     a  val1  somevalue1  anothervalue1
# 4   nok   nok         NaN            NaN
# 5     g  val7  somevalue7  anothervalue7
# 6     d  val4  somevalue4  anothervalue4
```